# Access key modifier doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="ftr_top_ctr-lft2">
<input type="button" title="Mark question" value="Mark" onclick="doCheck('process'); return false;" accesskey="M">
</div>
```

I tried to make it so there was a key users could use for quick access. But it seems like it doesn't work. Am I missing something? Also is there an easy way for me to tell the user how to use the access key (if it worked).

Maricel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To notify the user, add a label before or after the input with the notification text ("Press Alt-M"). Convention also says you can underline the character that should be pressed ("_M_ark").

To operate the access key, remember to use Alt.

Comment: Using Firefox 4 and I tried the ALT M key many times. It doesn't work at all. However clicking the button works good. Is there no way I can do an underline of the M? Press ALT-M doesn't exactly look good :-(

Comment: According to http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/treeview/accesskey-not-working-in-firefox-or-safari.aspx, the access key modifier in Firefox and Safari is Alt-Shift instead of Alt. Interesting...

Comment: Also, you can use a span within a label to do the underline: <label><span style="text-decoration:underline">M</span>ark</label>

Comment: Thanks. Yes ALT SHIFT M does work. Seems like a lot of effort for the user. Is there a way I can just make it so that when the user clicks enter then it will be the same as clicking the button?

Comment: To allow use of the Enter key, the input will need to be `type="submit"` and must be a part of a form.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<ALT> + <AccessKey>   in Internet explorer.
```

But in the Firefox you have to use

```
<ALT>+<SHIFT>+<AccesKey>
```

It will work :-)

Here is an Example for accesskeys..

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" 
   size="40" 
   id="myButton" 
   accesskey="Z" 
   value="Press Alt + Z to bring me into focus">
<button onclick="myButton.accessKey='N';">Change Access Key to N</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Label should help you. Try this.

```
<html>

<body> 
    <label for="txtAccessKey" accesskey="M" >Press M to access the text box. </label>
    <input id="txtAccessKey" /> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```